# Multilungual website in using Yii framework

Tags: yii, multilingual

I am new to Yii framework. How can I develop a multilingual website using it ? I need a document about it.

Would you give me some ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could begin with the wiki: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/?tag=multilanguage